# How's variable work? I am confuse on some java code from leetcode

Tags: java

```
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode p = l1, q =l2;
    int carry = 0;
    ListNode result = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode temp = result;
    
    while (p != null || q != null) {
        int x = p == null ? 0 : p.val;
        int y = q == null ? 0 : q.val;
        int sum = x + y + carry;
        carry = sum/10;
        int node = sum % 10;
        temp.next = new ListNode(node);
        p = (p != null && p.next != null) ? p.next : null;
        q = (q != null && q.next != null) ? q.next : null;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    
    if(carry != 0)
    {
        temp.next = new ListNode(carry);
    }
    
    return result.next;
}
```

My question is about variable temp and result. In my mind, temp and result are two different object with same initial value, and result should not modified as temp modified in the while loop.
Appreciate for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, when you assign a variable of one type to another variable of the same type, as you did with `ListNode temp = result;`, java automatically makes the `temp` variable a reference type. This means that there is no copying going on, and the `temp` variable points to the exact same object, and the exact same memory address, as the `result` variable. This means that when you do a change to the `temp` variable, the same change applies to the `result` object because, in reality, they are the same object.

Answer (score 1):

When you created  `ListNode result = new ListNode(0);` a new object is created and the variable `result` is the reference to the object. The statement `ListNode temp = result;` leads to assigning object reference of result to temp. Since both the variables are pointing to the same object modifying one modifies the other.

Comment: it that mean object variable always pass by reference in java?

Comment: When we pass the variable in a function, its pass by value as we copy the reference value. You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) for a good explanation

Comment: @ShawnL no, Java is **never** pass-by-reference